# Threading error when the return function is invoked

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm very new to threading, like an hour now, but I needed it for my code. I learned enough to use threads effectively in my situation but I'm stumped on how to get the return output from my function.

This is my thread invoke

```
threading.Thread(target = self.PageCollectionProcess(option) ).start()
```

When I try to return i get the output

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 524, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are calling [`Thread`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) in a wrong way:

```
threading.Thread(target = self.PageCollectionProcess(option) ).start()
```

should have been:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.PageCollectionProcess, args=(option,)).start()
```

think it of this way - in a very crude generalization, threading is a bit of lazy-loading; you tell a thread what to execute(a function and arguments for it) and the thread runs it later.

Comment: but how do you get the return, `results = threading.Thread(target=self.PageCollectionProcess, args=(option,)).start()` doesn't work.

Comment: @Crispy can't just call a function and take the return value in multi-threaded environment. There are tools for inter-thread communications, such as  `Queue`, `Event`, `Lock` ..  in python's `Threading` Module. Also you can run something in a separate thread and wait for the thread  to finish(by `thread.join()`), but this blocks the calling thread.